# android and python connection

Tags: python-3.x, android-studio, opencv3.0

I am doing python object detection and sending the image I receive to the virtual server I created with Flask. I want to capture the image at this url http://172.70.1.30:8000 in Android Studio, how can I do this?

How can I capture the image I took with Python in Android Studio?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.